# BizTalk Ack Propagation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a BizTalk interface receiving a HL7 message and passing the message on to a client's server. For this interface I have a two way RP and a solicit response SP. The current behaviour is that the two way RP will generate an ACK the moment it receives a message. The SP will then send the message to the client and the client will respond with an ACK. The SP will consume the ACK sent by the client server when the SP receives the ack. My question is how do I configure Biztalk such that the ACK from the SP gets propagated to the RP and back to the source in the same RP socket? I am trying to avoid orchestration so does this have to be a custom pipeline component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much reasearch and trail and error. It turns out that this is a native feature inside BizTalk 2013 R2. The reason it was not working before was because the RP was picking up the ACK generated in the RP's receive pipeline, specifcally the ACK generated by the disassembler. Hence when the ACK from client returns, it has no where to go and gets suspended in the RP. This can be addressed by creating a Party and setting the Ack Type to None with ack routing checked. 
[image: BTAHL7 Configuration Explorer]

Due to implementation limitations, I could not create a Party to utilize the above method. I had to code a custom pipeline component for the RP's Receive Pipeline to suppress the ACK from the disassembler instead. This worked just as well.

Comment: HOLD ON!  "Implementation limitations"???  Let me say, though you probably already know, such limitations are flat out wrong and well, just stupid.  Let us help you address the real problem, the limitations, so you can use BizTalk features correctly.  I've dealt with such "architects" before.

Comment: @Johns-305 To clarify, instead of using parties to prevent the disassembler in the receive port's receive pipeline from generating an ACK, i just added one small custom component to the end of the receive pipeline to consume the ack. The rest are all handled by BizTalk as it should. We cannot use parties becuause MSH.3 from multiple sources are the same across all of our messages, yet only one source wants the ack from the client. The rest of the sources are ok with the ack generated by BizTalk, they do not care for the client's ack.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your approach by using a HL7 Party and configuring Acknowledgment Type to 'None' on Acknowledgment Tab. This will make HL7 Disassembler not to generate acknowledgment on receiving the message. On send side once you receive acknowledgment from receiving system, make sure you have same EpmRRCorrelationToken context property as was in original message context. You may need to use a custom pipeline component on send port (receive side) to write this context property on ACK message. This will allow ACK message to go to RCV port. I have never done this before but it should work.

From a design perspective its not a very good idea, since the message sending system will wait for the acknowledgment until BizTalk is able to send the message out successfully and receive acknowledgment from message receiving system. You need to consider cases where your receiving system is having issues and not able to consume message or there is a planned down time. Most of the time sending system has time out set for acknowledgment and if they don't get the acknowledgment in that time frame then they retry, which creates duplicate message issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vikas. I want to clarify are you saying on the send side the EpmRRCorrelationToken for the ACK needs to be the same as the one genereted on the RP?

This is a requirement from source that they dont send the next message until they have an ACK from the client.

Comment: Yes, On received message you will have that context property

Answer (score 0):

First, **there is nothing wrong with using an Orchestration.  Don't worry about 'performance'.**

So, the correct BizTalk way would be to use an Orchestration manage the synchronization with the downstream system.